# in MySQL, How to split a string value and insert each token in a table?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, split, record, stored-functions

I have a table named "keywords" with the following fields:

ID [primary key] | keyword [varchar(255)]

keyword field of each record contains a string values like "this, is, only, a test"

I have no idea how to create a stored procedure to split this string with "," as delimiter and insert each token as a new record inside a new table.

thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

here, difficulty is to cut your string with a delimiter.
You need to declare a FUNCTION like this : 
http://fdegrelle.over-blog.com/article-1342263.html
after, you just need to store values in tables, it's easy.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have any kind of SPLIT() or EXPLODE() string function.  In a nutshell, you need to manually iterate over the string searching for commas and insert the value when you reach a delimiter (comma) or end of the string.  Alternatively you could try doing fancy gyrations with INSTR() and such, your mileage may vary.

I would suggest reading some of the comments at the bottom of the [String Functions reference page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html) at MySQL.  Do a search-on-page (Ctrl-F) for split and you'll see some useful ideas.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using instr() find the first occurance of the delimiter(,).
2. Substring() to split input string from zeroth char till first occurance-1 character 
    Now you have separated the first string.
    Insert separated string into table.
3. Use replace() to the input string to remove the first value.
4. Repeat steps 1 till 3, until your input string is empty.
   Hope this works..
   Good luck..